# Adding css to jquery children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a popup which would display on mouse hover by using jquery and some css. The code works as it should, however i can't add any CSS to the child elements of the popup window for some reason.

Here's the jquery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var $popup = $('.popup');
    $('area').on({
      mouseover : function(e){
        var $this = $(this),
            $obj = $('#'+$this.prop('alt'));
        $popup.text($obj.text()).css({
          top: '90%',
          left: '24.8%',
          color: 'orange',
          }).show();
      },
      mouseout: function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            $obj = $('#'+$this.prop('alt'));          
        $popup.hide(0).empty();
      }
    });
    });
```

And here's the popup html code containing what is displayed in the popup. Nothing happens when i try to add the css to the classes displayed inside popup.

```
<div class="stanovanje" id="n1s1">
<h2>Področje 1</h2>
  <div class="koda">Koda:<br><p>1-12-123-S1</p></div><div class="tip">Tip:<br><p>A1</p></div><div class="povrsina">Površina:<br>84.24m</div> <div class="vrsta">Vrsta:<br>z balkonom/teraso</div><div class="cena">Cena:<br>120000€</div>
</div>
<div class="stanovanje" id="n1s2">
  <div class="koda">Koda:<br><p>1-12-123-S2</p></div><div class="tip">Tip:<br><p>A2</p></div><div class="povrsina">Površina:<br>74.24m</div> <div class="vrsta">Vrsta:<br>z balkonom/teraso</div><div class="cena">Cena:<br>140000€</div>
</div>
<div class="popup"></div>
```

Thanks for reading and all the answers!

Comment: where's your area tag as you've defined this on click

Comment: `$('area')` where is it?

Comment: If that is all the CSS there is, setting `top` and `left` won't do anything; those only work for positioned elements.

Comment: Are you able to add text using  $popup.text($obj.text()) ??

Comment: After term orange remove the comma.it was throwing errors.I did find area you are specifying.

Comment: The CSS added with jquery works fine, im not able to add the CSS code for elements inside the popup such as .koda, .tip, .vrsta classes which are inside the popup. 

When i add css commands for these elements to my stylesheet nothing happens with them, except for the css from jquery

Comment: @MujtabaHaider

Yes im able to add text with that code. However im not able to position divs inside that popup text with css for some reason.

Comment: Are you able to add color?

Comment: Yes orange color is added to the whole text inside popup.

Comment: as @MrLister said, left and top properties work for positioned elements, you should also add position: 'relative' or whatever you want

Comment: @rishariss then @MrLister's comment is the solution, you should set at least `position: absolute` (or  `fixed`)

Comment: This would position the whole popup window, i dont have problems with that. I want to position divs inside the popup but they dont get affected by my css code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

top or left props would work with positioned elem
Update 2: I hope It will work this way

JS

```
var $popup = $('.popup');   
$popup.html($obj.html());
$('.popup div').css({
    top: '90%',
    left: '24.8%',
    color: 'orange',
position: 'relative' //absolute
});
$popup.show();
```

Comment: Yes but this will position the whole popup window. I want to position elements inside the popup beacause they are now displayed as one line of text.
I added divs with classes to separate parts of text, as u can see in first post, but they dont get affected by CSS which i add to them.

Comment: The popup gets displayed on mouse hover, but its empty as there is no content inside it anymore.

Comment: Yes, text is inside div if that is what you mean?

This is the text that should get displayed in the popup:




<div class="stanovanje" id="n1s2">
  <div class="koda">Koda:<br><p>1-12-123-S2</p></div><div class="tip">Tip:<br><p>A2</p></div><div class="povrsina">Površina:<br>74.24m</div> <div class="vrsta">Vrsta:<br>z balkonom/teraso</div><div class="cena">Cena:<br>140000€</div>
</div>

As you can see that text is made of several divs with classes, but those divs dont get affected by any CSS code, instead they are displayed as one line of text.

Comment: Just updated again. You should apply CSS on div inside popup, instead of on popup

Comment: Your last update solved everything, thank you very much good sir!

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong code too, you need to remove last comma:

```
$popup.text($obj.text()).css({
    top: '90%',
    left: '24.8%',
    color: 'orange',
}).show();
```

Should be:

```
$popup.text($obj.text()).css({
    top: '90%',
    left: '24.8%',
    color: 'orange'
}).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing, but it didnt help me with adding CSS to the elements inside the popup, not the popup itself.